# Pandas plot without specifying index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Given the data:

```
Column1; Column2; Column3
1; 4; 6
2; 2; 6
3; 3; 8
4; 1; 1
5; 4; 2
```

I can plot it via:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv',delimiter='; ', engine='python')
titles = list(df)
for title in titles:
    if title == titles[0]:
        continue
    df.plot(titles[0],title, linestyle='--', marker='o')
    plt.savefig(title+'.png')
```

But if, instead, data was missing `Column1` like:

```
Column2; Column3
4; 6
2; 6
3; 8
1; 1
4; 2
```

How do I plot it?

May be, something like `df.plot(title, linestyle='--', marker='o')`?

Comment: There are lot's of ways to plot it!  I need a better understanding of what you are trying to plot.

Comment: I would like to plot `Column2 X index`, but index is missing.

Comment: @KcFnMi, IIUC, you could perform `reset_index` to set the `DF`'s index to the default integer index and then pass `Column2` as the y arg of the plot as: `df.reset_index().plot(y='Column2', linestyle='--', marker='o')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you could reset index and set it as you would like:

```
In[11]: df
Out[11]: 
   Column1   Column2   Column3
0        1         4         6
1        2         2         6
2        3         3         8
3        4         1         1
4        5         4         2
```

so if you want to plot col 2 as X axis and 3 as Y axis you could do something like:

```
df.set_index('Column2')['Column3'].plot()
```

Comment: I'll accept an answer showing how to add and index column.